# Unable to resolve module 'react-navigation' from .../App.js: Module 'react-navigation' does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have just setup an app to start building it out and I keep getting this error from my App.js. This is a part of a udemy course in which I have followed every instruction to a T... so I am beyond confused of what the hell is happening and I have followed every suggestion I can find. `Unable to resolve module react-navigation from /Users/3x7r3m157/Development/React-Native/food/App.js: Module react-navigation does not exist in the Haste module map`.

```
This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.

facebook::ReactABI35_0_0::JSIExecutor::defaultTimeoutInvoker(std::__1::function<void ()> const&, std::__1::function<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > ()>)
facebook::ReactABI35_0_0::JSIExecutor::defaultTimeoutInvoker(std::__1::function<void ()> const&, std::__1::function<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > ()>)
ED0789CD-8D80-39F4-9651-D8707D9C0337
ED0789CD-8D80-39F4-9651-D8707D9C0337
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
97285ACB-7B21-393A-ABF6-03F1DBB5D2A2
97285ACB-7B21-393A-ABF6-03F1DBB5D2A2
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
UIApplicationMain
Exponent
0DC9A4BA-C3E8-3487-99DB-1B5C86597AF5
```

Here is my App.js:

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import SearchScreen from './src/screens/SearchScreen';

const navigator = createStackNavigator ({
  Search: SearchScreen
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Search',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    title: 'BusinessSearch'
  }
});

export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

Comment: have you installed react-navigation? You should add your package.json to this question, since the error seems to be related to it

Comment: That was totally it. Devils in the details...thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to install react-navigation with `npm i react-navigation`

Comment: Thank you! Seems to be the little details that trip me up

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to use CMD to run this commands.

1. If your system is Windows, set your environment variable, add `%SystemRoot%\system32` to your `PATH` I met this error yesterday，hope it works to you. Don't forget to reboot you PC.

After that :

2. Create your project : `npx expo-cli init <projectname>`

Then :

1. Install React Navigation :

   ```
   npm install react-navigation
   ```
2. Install Dependencies :

   ```
   expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
   ```
3. Install React Navigation Stack :

   ```
   npm install react-navigation-stack @react-native-community/masked-view
   ```
4. Start the app and clear cache with `npm start -c`.

Update Imports
Our imports in the upcoming lecture will now look like this :

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
```

Errors?

If you are still seeing errors and complaints about packages, do the following :

1. `rm -r node_modules`
2. `rm package-lock.json`
3. `expo upgrade`
4. `npm start -c`

Answer (score 1):

Do this it will definitely work :

```
npm install --legecy-peer-deps react-navigation
```

**or**

```
npm install --legecy-peer-deps react-navigation --force
```