# Expo CLI Unable to resolve module @react-navigation/native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have installed all the dependcies but I still get this below:
Using Expo-CLI?

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle.



Unable to resolve module @react-navigation/native from /home/jonteyh/React_Native/projects/MealsToGo/App.js: @react-navigation/native could not be found within the project or in these directories:

  ../../../node_modules/@react-navigation



If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:

 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all

 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install

 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache

 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*

  3 | import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components/native";

  4 | import { theme } from "./src/infrastructure/theme";

> 5 | import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

    |                                      ^

  6 | //import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";

  7 |

  8 | import {

› Stopped server
```

I have tried to remove .expo, node_modules but is still get this errors?

How can I solve this?

And I have tried with the steps above?

Comment: This error occurs because you haven't installed `react-navigation`.

Comment: I used yarn add @react-navigation/native

Comment: you might have installed the module but didn't re-built your project to rebuilt it try for Android or iOS `react-native run-android` or` react-native run-ios`.

Comment: Also there is a lot of possible answers did you search for answer on Stack Overflow beacause more than 10 answers which might solve your problem.

Comment: @Kevin M. Mansour I am using expo-cli??

Comment: @Kevin M. Mansour i have tried everything clear the cache reinstall?

Comment: My Bad, Sorry I missed out that you are using expo-cli can you add that in title?

Comment: Also I found in Docs of https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/ that you must install all this modules `expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view` `yarn add react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`

Comment: @Kevin M. Mansour I have done all this But thanks!

Comment: Hmm; See this also https://stackoverflow.com/a/61933009/14945696. Do you have written any code to your project or it just Blank Project.

Comment: Do you have written any code to your project or it just Blank Project.

Comment: I have written a code it is based on Udemy course?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231895/discussion-between-kevin-m-mansour-and-john).

Comment: I was just recommended to create blank Project and Install your dependcies slowly and correctly which may lead to move your file from Old one into the newly created. I think that might work. but you will waste your time a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Kevin M. Mansour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14945696/) for helping me solve this issue!

First, go to your project and delete `.expo`, `node_modules`, and `yarn.lock`.

After you have deleted these files install your dependencies:

```
yarn add @react-navigation/native
```

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

After that run the following command:

```
expo r -c
```

After that, all the errors disappeared!
Delete the `yarn.lock` file if your project is not too big it may introduce some errors if you have a big project!
So be careful about deleting the `yarn.lock` file.